# Get the last 2 autoincrement ID

Tags: php, mysql

I managed to get the last ID for the last insert query but nor for the second one. How Can I achieve this? I need both to populate the join table

```
$query="INSERT INTO  $dbname.Product (Description, ***, **, **, **) VALUES ('$des','$**', '$**', '$**', '$**')";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
        $id =  mysqli_insert_id($conn);
        $query2 = "INSERT INTO  $dbname.Classification (**, **, **) VALUES ('$**', '$**', '$***')";     

        $result2 = mysqli_query($conn,$query2); 
        $id2 =  mysqli_insert_id($conn);
        echo $id;
        echo $id2;   //print the same ID as $id2
```

Comment: What makes you think it's wrong? Since you are not inserting in the same table, it's possible that the ID is the same. Also: SQL injection...

Comment: Thanks. I found My mistake, I forgot change the ID in Classification Table to AUTO INCREMENT

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Answer (score 1):

If you evaluate that there are no risk for two products to be created by two different user within the same second, you could use a query like this one.

```
INSERT INTO $dbname.myTable (id_product, id_classification) VALUES((SELECT id_product FROM $dbname.Product ORDER BY id_product DESC LIMIT 1), (SELECT id_classification FROM $dbname.Classification  ORDER BY id_classification DESC LIMIT 1));
```

If lot of people can create products at the same and the risk of conflicts are high, then I'd used a stored procedure and I'd stored the value of the last inserted id in a variable after each query.

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE createProduct(
[your paramters],
dbName AS VARCHAR(50)
) 
BEGIN

    DECLARE idProduct INT(10) UNSIGNED;
    DECLARE idClassification INT(10) UNSIGNED;

    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FROM SQLEXCEPTION BEGIN
        ROLLBACK;
        RESIGNAL;
    END;

    START TRANSACTION;

    INSERT INTO  dbname.Product (Description, ***, **, **, **) VALUES ('$des','$**', '$**', '$**', '$**');

    SET idProduct = LAST_INSERTED_ID();

    INSERT INTO dbname.Classification (**, **, **) VALUES ('$**', '$**', '$***');

    SET idClassification = LAST_INSERTED_ID();

    INSERT INTO $dbname.myTable (id_product, id_classification) VALUES (idProduct, idClassification);

    COMMIT;

END//
```